# Opening PDF in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, itext, pdfbox, icepdf

I am making a PDF reader using java and I want to open the PDF file in my own application's JFrame so that I can make my own features. Is there a way to do that?
I am using "iText","pdfBox", and "ICEpdf" to manipulate the PDF document.

Comment: For PDFBox, get the source code and look at PDFReader.java and PDFPagePanel.java. But I'd say your question is rather broad and is likely to be flagged.

Comment: You can use method `convertToImage` of class `PDPage`, and then show the image on JFrame.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static void pdfViewerICE() {
        String filePath = "PDF_URL";
        // build a controller
        controller = new SwingController();

        // Build a SwingViewFactory configured with the controller
        SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);
           PropertiesManager properties = new PropertiesManager(
                System.getProperties(),
                 ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE));

   properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL, "1.75");

        // Use the factory to build a JPanel that is pre-configured
        //with a complete, active Viewer UI.
       JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

        controller.openDocument(filePath);
      }
```

The above code opens PDF using ICEPDF via your java program. 
Note: Include ICEPDF jar (icepdf-viewer.jar,icepdf-core.jar ) in your classpath http://www.icesoft.org/java/downloads/icepdf-downloads.jsf

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how can I open remote pdfs using this. When I put the URL to the file, I get the message that icepdf couldn't open the file because it has been corrupted of have incorrect file format even though the pdf was fine.

Comment: which version that you're using it there @Nesh ?